# Handling client disconnect/abort during streaming response in `Deno.serve`

Tags: javascript, deno

I have some Deno server code that looks roughly like this:

```js
Deno.serve((req) => {
  let asyncIterator = getChunkIterator(req.url);

  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    async pull(controller) {
      try {
        const { value, done } = await asyncIterator.next();
        if (done) {
          controller.close();
          return;
        }
        controller.enqueue(value);
      } catch (err) {
        controller.error(err);
      }
    }
  });
  
  let response = new Response(stream);
  return response;
});
```

The response streaming can take several seconds, and the client may disconnect half-way through. I need to detect this so that I can stop the (separate) "worker" server that is producing the chunks of data for that client.

I have no idea how to do this, since with `Deno.serve` you just `return` the `Response` object, rather than being given a stream to write to.

Comment: From what I've read, you can add a `cancel() {...}` method in `new ReadableStream({` which will be called if the client disconnects - you can stop the worker in that function

Comment: Thank you! Looks like `request.signal.addEventListener("abort", function() {...})` should work too, but currently has a bug: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/10829#issuecomment-1728906635

Please feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `cancel` method of the `ReadableStream`

Starting from Deno version 1.36.4, connection drops will be accurately detected when responding with a `ReadableStream`, and the `cancel` method will be called with the reason `"resource closed"` (implemented in this [commit](https://github.com/denoland/deno/commit/9b0130770467ef11f4c0d4acbb42a9f0cf4bfe7f))

```js
Deno.serve((req) => {
  let asyncIterator = getChunkIterator(req.url);

  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    async pull(controller) {
     /* ... */
    },

    cancel(reason) {
      // reason === 'resource closed' when connection drops
      // cleanup your resource
    }
  });
  
  let response = new Response(stream);
  return response;
});
```